# Read a Excel file with exceljs syncrronuously

Tags: node.js, excel, npm, exceljs

I'm trying to read a excel file into a csv-like looking array `[ArrayLine1,ArrayLine2,..]` with exceljs in nodejs. Exceljs has probably no solution to read a file synchronuously, so I have to build a solution around that. Because of my program in electron with frontend progess display etc. must it run synchronuously. But all my attempts with async functions around the exceljs code doesn't work with the synchronuous frontend.

```
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook()

var raw = []
var line
workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename).then(() => {

    workbook.eachSheet((sheet, sid) => {

       sheet.eachRow((row, rid) => {

           line = []
           row.eachCell((cell, cid) => {
               
               line.push(cell.value)
           })
           
           raw.push(line)
       })
    })
})

//use raw / write the raw to another file
console.log(raw) //echo's: []
```

Comment: *Because of my program in electron with frontend progess display etc. must it run syncronly* - I do not understand this phrase, rather it's the other way around. Can you elaborate?

Comment: my frontend helper function works with ipc and if i use my helper function inside the read callable the ipc main doesnt receive any content

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it invoking the `workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)` function with `await` modificator inside on my `async` function, so my code await for the complete excel read until continue with the execution